# create 3d perpendicular walls using Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, rectangles

i am wondering if it's possible to create 3d perpendicular walls using Three.js as on this image [image]

i tried to use THREE.Shape to draw a rectangle but i don't know how to add more perpendicular or parallel rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Store the top corners of each wall as a "ring" of 3d vertices going either clockwise or anti-clockwise. (Each roof vertex can have a different z value if you like for non-flat roofs, or just set them all to the same height.)

Each wall is a subsequent pair of vertices in the list.

For each wall, draw a simple plane geometry and mesh. It's easy to manually create the two faces for the plane rather than messing around with other geometry types.

```
//Simple A-frame roof
var roofVertices = [
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0), new THREE.Vector3(10, 15, 0), new THREE.Vector3(20, 10, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(20, 10, 20), new THREE.Vector3(10, 15, 20), new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 20)
];

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xccffcc,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

for (var i = 0; i < roofVertices.length; i++) {

    var v1 = roofVertices[i];
    var v2 = roofVertices[(i+1)%roofVertices.length];//wrap last vertex back to start

    var wallGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    wallGeometry.vertices = [
        v1,
        v2,
        new THREE.Vector3(v1.x, 0, v1.z),
        new THREE.Vector3(v2.x, 0, v2.z)
    ];

    //always the same for simple 2-triangle plane
    wallGeometry.faces = [new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2), new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 3)];

    wallGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
    wallGeometry.computeVertexNormals();

    var wallMesh = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, material);
    scene.add(wallMesh);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work with the latest version of the three js, @pythonjsgo will you please update your code?

Answer (score -1):

Simply build different Mesh obj and place them the way you want, this would be an example

```
var geometryLateral = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 2, 5);
var wall1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometryLateral, material);
scene.add(wall1);
wall1.position.x=-1;
var wall2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometryLateral, material);
scene.add(wall2);
wall2.position.x=1;
```

The two walls here are facing each other.